Jasper reports: one line per value instead of an array of values
​
Hi everyone, I'm new to Jasper Reports.
I'm working on my first JRXML template and the headers rendering is working as expected.
I'm encountering difficulties while it comes to the values/data. I'm expecting jasper to create a line per occurrence of data while it's display the whole array of values.
Since it's my first jasper template please give me any advices that could help for the readability.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
    name="manual-lines" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802"
    leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter"
        value="reports/tv5-salesdocument-v1/DataAdapter2.jrdax" />
    <style name="Headers" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000" />
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000" />
            <bottomPen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000" />
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000" />
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Values" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000" />
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000" />
        </box>
    </style>

    <queryString language="json"><![CDATA[]]></queryString>
    <field name="headers.ref" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.station" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.effectiveOn" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.quantity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.costPerUnit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.discountAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="headers.totalCost" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <field name="data.ref" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.station" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.effectiveOn" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.quantity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.costPerUnit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.discountAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="data.totalCost" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <columnHeader>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="-20" y="0" width="20" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.ref}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="0" y="0" width="52" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.station}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="52" y="0" width="177" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="229" y="0" width="83" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.effectiveOn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="312" y="0" width="50" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="362" y="0" width="52" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.costPerUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="414" y="0" width="48" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.discountAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Headers" x="462" y="0" width="48" height="31" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headers.totalCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="10" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="-20" y="0" width="20" height="10" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.ref}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="0" y="0" width="52" height="10" />
                <box leftPadding="2" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.station}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="52" y="0" width="177" height="10" />
                <box leftPadding="2" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="229" y="0" width="83" height="10" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.effectiveOn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="312" y="0" width="50" height="10" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="362" y="0" width="52" height="10" />
                <box rightPadding="2" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.costPerUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="414" y="0" width="48" height="10" />
                <box rightPadding="2" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.discountAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement style="Values" x="462" y="0" width="48" height="10" />
                <box rightPadding="2" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data.totalCost}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch" height="1">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="530" height="1" />
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>

</jasperReport>

​


if any question look this enter link description here

Each time I'm trying to publish in the jasper community it display me a ban message on a fresh account

@ethicnology show  ban message  .....

for no reason, its newly created account and my account is not banned from the website it show this message only when i try to post
